# How can javaScript library and css files load before component load in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, react-component, react-data-table-component

How can javaScript library and css files load before reactjs component load.

I am converting dataTable Html template  to react component but javaScript library and css files are isn't loaded with components.

How can I solved it. Can any one help me?

Comment: Please show your code so others can make specific recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these lines at your very first component like app.js which renders first ater index.js(for class based components)

```
    componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://use.typekit.net/foobar.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

And for functional components

```
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://use.typekit.net/foobar.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use import [ which js library you want to use ]
and then put this syntax at the js file top like as you import react;

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
```